# How to identify Firebase Firestore errors and exceptions in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
public static void getMember(String id, DataListener<Member> listener){
        FirebaseAgent.getMemberDocumentReference(id).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists())
                    listener.onDataReady(documentSnapshot.toObject(Member.class));
                else
                    listener.onDataNotFound(MEMBER_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // .............. error identification ................
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to build a helper function with returns that error Firebase throws and I want to store those errors inside an enum

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

An operation of reading a document from Firestore might indeed fail, due to many reasons. So assuming that `FirebaseAgent.getMemberDocumentReference(id)` returns an object of type [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference), to handle the errors, please note that the Exception that might be thrown is of type [FirebaseFirestoreException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException).

> I want to build a helper function with returns which error Firebase throws and I want to store those errors inside an enum.

That's a good idea, but please note that there is already an enum present inside the `FirebaseFirestoreException` class, which is called [Code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code), where you can find all Cloud Firestore status codes. So when such an Exception is thrown you can check the [code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException#code()) field against these status codes, and the action according to the use case of your app.

One of the most known Exception that is thrown when you read data from Firestore, is called [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code#PERMISSION_DENIED). If you want to read more about that, please check the resource below:

- [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404)

Comment: Hey Mouad. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?